# How to Add HostPort prometheus-rancher-monitoring-prometheus to query from external nodes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, k8s-cluster-role

I have prometheus-rancher-monitoring-prometheus pod running in one of the nodes in the cluster inside the Namespace: cattle-monitoring-system. I can access the prometheus within the cluster through the containerPort 9090.

I would like to access this pod from an external node out of cluster. I am trying to add the hostPort 9090 in statefulset but it is not updating. How can I access it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a HostPort you should define an Ingress that listens for the incoming connections on ports 80 and 443 for HTTP and HTTPS requests, respectively, and forwards the requests to the hostPort

```
paths:
  - backend:
      serviceName: service-name
      servicePort: 9090
```